# c# using a string variable to change a databinding

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, data-binding, bindingsource

When I press a button, my databinding goes to a record and pulls information from a cell. I then set the text from that cell to a string variable. I would like to be able to use that string as part of the name for my databinding. So, the information in a certain column of a table influences which datasource I am now bound to.

edit:

For those who have trouble visualizing from my lacking description

```
public string BindingSource;

public void WhichBindingSource(){

    BindingSource = txtSetupTable.Text; 

}

public void SaveToProperBindingSource(){

    this.{WhichTable}BindingSource.EndEdit();   

}
```

**txtSetupTable is bound to a table**

**WhichTable would be the name of a table that exists**

Comment: Check this first...http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please see my edited post

Comment: I assume WPF.  How you a binding now.

Comment: I'm just using if statements, so if BindingSource == 1, this._1BindingSource

Comment: Basically I want to write the line: